# Eloquent relationship join "where not in array" filter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Okay..

I have "maybe a simple" questing. I have a recipe model with a toMany relation to a ingredients model and a tag model ..

I need a way to filter out recipes that has a specific tag ( no problem there ) .. and I also want to filter ( exclude ) recipes that has some specific ingrediens..

```
$recipe = Recipe::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tagId, $maxCal) {
    $q->where('tag_key', $tagId);
})
->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function ($q) use ($excludeIngredientGroups) {
    $q->whereNotIn('ingredient_group_key', $excludeIngredientGroups);
})
```

$excludeIngredientGroups is an array.

sql error .. : Unknown column 'ingredient.ingredient_group_key' in 'where clause'

```
class Recipe extends Base
{
    protected $table = "recipes";

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RecipeIngredient', 'recipe_id', 'id')
    }


class RecipeIngredient extends Base
{
    protected $table = "recipes_ingredients";

    public function ingredient(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ingredient', 'ingredient_key', 'key');
    }
    public function recipe(){
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\Models\Recipe","recipe_id","id");
    }
```

does it make sense?

Comment: Double check your table name, shouldn't it be in plural form?

Comment: ingredient_group_key is a column on the ingredients model .. but the sub query is the relation table i think, I'm not that hard to eloquent yet.

Comment: what is the table name of the ingredients model?

Comment: recipes (recipe model) - ingredients (ingredients model) - recipes_ingredients (join table with recipe_id and ingredient_key )

Comment: Could you share Recipe model ?

Comment: Yep .. check the updated version of the question ;)

Comment: you have many to many relation between recipe and ingredients and pivot model RecipeIngredient and you make the relation(ingredients) with the pivot table?

Comment: what is table structure for RecipeIngredient model table?

Comment: Now with some more info in the questing field

Comment: is it possible that you have two relation with name 'ingredients' one for RecipeIngredient and another for Ingredient ? please try change the name of the relation see if that make any difference

Comment: also it doesn't make sense to have ingredient_group_key column in recipes_ingredients table

Comment: ingredient_group_key column is on the ingredient table .. that is the hard part. otherwise it was not a problem ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216203/discussion-between-pkdkk-and-omr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you relations in Recipe Model should be :

1- ingredients: belongsToMany Ingredient model

2- recipeIngredients hasMany RecipeIngredient model

```
class Recipe extends Base
{
    protected $table = "recipes";

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Ingredient', 'recipes_ingredients','recipe_id','ingredient_key');
    }
public function recipeIngredients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RecipeIngredient', 'recipe_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

another note:

> ->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function ($q) use ($excludeIngredientGroups) {
>       $q->whereNotIn('ingredient_group_key', $excludeIngredientGroups); })

whereNotIn shoud be: whereIn, since you use whereDoesntHave